# Cannot start ASP.NET Boilerplate frontend from latest template

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I created a new template yesterday (15 Aug 2017) and after installing all the frontend dependencies using `npm install` when I run `npm start` I get a lot of errors such as:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@shared/session/app-session.service'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@shared/app-component-base'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@shared/service-proxies/service-proxies'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@abp/multi-tenancy/abp-multi-tenancy.service'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@abp/settings/setting.service'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@abp/notify/notify.service'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@abp/features/feature-checker.service'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@abp/localization/localization.service'
```

If I look in `node_modules` I see I do have the **abp-ng2-module** and **abp-web-resources** folders.

I think there's one or more dependencies missing from the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete node_modules folder and install with yarn